# Swap Elements of a continuous List, possible?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a function

```
MinVarGeneralThermal1[T, 5, d]
```

which yields me the following list:

```
{{0.00917615, 0.0136892, 0.0204219, 0.0304659, 0.0454498, 0.10115,
 0.225114, 0.335831, 0.150899, 0.0678031}}
```

As you can see these are not single pairs of entires of the form

```
{{1},{2},{3},{4},...}
```

which makes it **not possible** for me to target single entries using a command like

```
MinVarGeneralThermal1[T, 5, d][[3]]
```

Is it possible to write a **swap** command that works something like this

```
swap[MinVarGeneralThermal1[T, 5, d],{1,3}]
```

which would essentially swap the first and third entries of the list (for example) ? In the end I want to be able to swap any two entries I want.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 6):

I am not sure that I fully get your problem. You can always access individual elements of the nested list you have, e.g. by using `yourList[[1, 3]]`.

However, this may work for you:

```
ClearAll[swap]
swap[list_List, pair_?(VectorQ[#, IntegerQ] &)] := {Permute[list[[1]], Cycles[{pair}]]}
```

Here is an example usage on a made-up list:

```
list = {CharacterRange["a", "g"]}
swap[list, {2, 3}]

(* Out:
{{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"}}
{{"a", "c", "b", "d", "e", "f", "g"}}
*)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
sWap[a : {{__}}, pair_] :=  Module[{l = a}, l[[1, pair]] = l[[1, Reverse @ pair]]; l]

MinVarGeneralThermal1[T, 5, d]
```

> {{0.00917615,0.0136892,0.0204219,0.0304659,0.0454498,0.10115,0.225114,0.335831,0.150899,0.0678031}}

```
sWap[MinVarGeneralThermal1[T, 5, d], {1, 3}]
```

> {0.0204219,0.0136892,0.00917615,0.0304659,0.0454498,0.10115,0.225114,0.335831,0.150899,0.0678031}}

Answer (score 4):

```
list = CharacterRange["a", "g"];

SubsetMap[RotateLeft, list, {2, 3}]
```

{"a", "c", "b", "d", "e", "f", "g"}

To swap more than one element:

```
SubsetMap[RotateLeft, list, {2, 3, 4}]
```

{"a", "c", "d", "b", "e", "f", "g"}

If you want to start with the double brackets:

```
list = {CharacterRange["a", "g"]};

{SubsetMap[RotateLeft, list[[1]], {2, 3}]}
```

{{"a", "c", "b", "d", "e", "f", "g"}}